# Is there a simple way to convert a JSON URL into a downloadable PDF using PHP?

Tags: php, json, pdf

I have just started learning PHP so I am not so familiar with this but any help is really appreciated and hope to help others similar with this too.

So basically it is easy to parse the JSON URL using the GET method request:(just for example)

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://jsonexample.com/");
$json = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($json);
?>
```

How to convert the JSON data inside the URL into pdf?

Comment: This will be fiddly - I suggest using a webpage to pdf API. PHP HTML to PDF libraries generally require HTML with perfect syntax/no errors and are still quite fussy.

Comment: I can't help you specifically, but the short answer is you don't "convert the JSON" to PDF. Instead, you create a dynamic PDF somehow, and the most common way it HTML. You can search for "PHP HTML to PDF" and you'll find a bunch of solutions. All you need to do is figure out how to transform your JSON into nice-looking HTML.

Comment: So there is no way for this then. I don't know if HTML generates a report but I'll try to look for it. Thanks for the answers, really appreciated :)